# How can I determining a date/time interval between grouping variables of different lengths using tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In my dataset an ID can appear once, twice, or three or more times. I'm trying to work out the time interval between each of these different instances. i.e. What is the interval between the first and second appearance of ID "AA" AND what is the interval between the first and second, and second and third appearance of ID "DD" etc etc.

Here's some sample data to illustrate:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(100)
ID <- c("AA", "AA", "AB", "AB", "AC", "AC", "AD", "DD", "DD", "DD", 
   "CA", "CA", "FS", "FS", "FS", "BA", "BA", "TZ", "TZ", "TZ")
rowNum <- c(1:20)
date <- c("2013-05-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-10-01", "2015-09-01", 
  "2014-10-01", "2015-09-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2013-08-01", 
  "2013-05-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-12-01", "2010-09-01", "2012-06-01", 
  "2013-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-09-01", "2015-02-01", "2016-04-01", 
  "2017-01-01")

sampleData <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, rowNum, date)) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  mutate(value_x = runif(length(ID))) %>%
  mutate(value_y = runif(length(ID))) %>%
  mutate(value_z = runif(length(ID)))
```

My initial thought was to spread the data using an index and use `mutate` to work out the difference:

```
test2 <- sampleData %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(index = row_number(ID)) %>%
   spread(index, date) %>%
   mutate(time_interval1_2 = interval(`1`, `2`))
```

However using this approach the dates end up on different rows, so I can't calculate the difference between them. Any ideas for how to solve this little problem using the `tidyverse` would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what would be your expected output for the sample data you give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the column `Diff`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

sampleData2 <- sampleData %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff = date - lag(date)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(100)
ID <- c("AA", "AA", "AB", "AB", "AC", "AC", "AD", "DD", "DD", "DD", 
        "CA", "CA", "FS", "FS", "FS", "BA", "BA", "TZ", "TZ", "TZ")
rowNum <- c(1:20)
date <- c("2013-05-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-10-01", "2015-09-01", 
          "2014-10-01", "2015-09-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2013-08-01", 
          "2013-05-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-12-01", "2010-09-01", "2012-06-01", 
          "2013-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-09-01", "2015-02-01", "2016-04-01", 
          "2017-01-01")
```